# Nursing kittens on adult male cats

Tags: cats, feeding

---

I have two kittens from different litters.  They continually try to nurse off my (also not related) male adult cat.  Is this harmful to any involved?

Comment: See the answers on the questions I have provided above, if you do not find it answers your question please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I assume they are young and don't know what's what yet so I would not worry about it unless they stop nursing from their mother.